# Writing to a text file, last entry is missing

Tags: python, file, text

This code calls no errors, but my text file is not getting betty and her grade. It's only getting the first three out of the four combinations. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
students = ['fred','wilma','barney','betty']
grades = [100,75,80,90]
for i in range(4):
    file = open("grades3.txt", "a")
    entry = students[i] + "-" + str(grades[i]) + '\n'
    file.write(entry)
file.close
```

Comment: You should either use `open()` outside of the loop, or `with open("grades3.txt", "a") as file:`.

Comment: Your code should work fine. just delete the file & run again. if that doesn't work, then try above mentioned way

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal They should use `with` either way. It's just simpler.

Comment: file.close is a function, you must call this like: `file.close()`. Also you might want to try and indent the close so it closes every iteration. Or just open the file outside the loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with this code in a script. Are you running it in a REPL? If so, I think the file gets flushed every time you open it again, but then you're not actually closing it (should be `file.close()`), so the last line doesn't get flushed, not until you exit the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use use `with open() as ...` to automatically open, close and assign the file handle to a variable:

```py
students = ['fred','wilma','barney','betty']
grades = [100,75,80,90]
with open("grades3.txt", "a") as file:
    for i in range(4):
        entry = students[i] + "-" + str(grades[i]) + '\n'
        file.write(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are opening the file each iteration of the loop, as well as not calling the `file.close` function. You should have something like this:

```py
students = ['fred','wilma','barney','betty']
grades = [100,75,80,90]
file = open("grades3.txt", "a")
for i in range(4):
    entry = students[i] + "-" + str(grades[i]) + '\n'
    file.write(entry)
file.close()
```

Comment: Use `with` instead, it's easier. See [B's answer](/a/75367193/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use an approach like this instead of using `range()`:

```
students = ['fred','wilma','barney','betty']
grades = [100,75,80,90]
with open("grades3.txt","a") as f:
    for student, grade in zip(students,grades):
        f.write(f"{student}-{grade}\n")
```

Comment: `zip` is irrelevant to the problem, though it is probably a better approach.

Comment: Why not go one step further and use list comprehension? `[f.write(f"{student}-{grade}\n") for student, grade in zip(students, grades)]`